# FFmpeg post video stream to a webservice cause error 'chunked body too large'

Tags: web-services, post, ffmpeg

I have a webservice which is developped by Tornado. Now I use FFmpeg to post video stream data to service. After some time, the process is down and rise an error like:

```
[I 170928 07:33:55 http1connection:253] Malformed HTTP message from 172.18.130.125: chunked body too large
```

I use command like:

```
ffmpeg -s 1240x720 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -b:v 0 -q:v 1 -f mpegts -c:v mpeg1video -b 800k -r 30 http://10.4.245.152:9090/video/live
```

Should I use ffmpeg to continue post video stream to a webservice?

Comment: Looks like you are hitting the max_body_size of the tornado web service, and it shuts down the stream. You can increase this size so it will take longer before you run into the same issue. You may want to consider alternate approaches if your intention is to continuously stream to the server.

Comment: Increasing this size is a method for the project. But it can't solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I test, I think the reason of this problem is about service server. I check my service server and find the size of chunk data is limit.